# Whats going on here with cctype?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std

To my surprise the following code compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
   std::string s="nawaz";
   std::string S;
   std::transform(s.begin(),s.end(), std::back_inserter(S), ::toupper);
   std::cout << S ;
}
```

I had expected it to fail because of the `::toupper` which I believed should be in the `std` namespace. A quick check of cctype shows that it is but it is imported from the root namesapce (Mystery solved there).

```
namespace std
{
  // Other similar `using` deleted for brevity.
  using ::toupper;
}
```

So first problem solved but if I change the `transform()` line above too:

```
std::transform(s.begin(),s.end(), std::back_inserter(S), std::toupper);
```

I would now expect this to now also compile. But I get a compiler error:

> kk.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to `transform(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::cha
>   r_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::back_insert_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, <***unresolved overloaded function type***>)'

Which with manual editing resolved too:

```
kk.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to
         `transform(iterator<std::string>,
                    iterator<std::string>,
                    std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>,
                    <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: +1 for asking this question. Even I want to know!

Comment: Looks like a GCC bug to me.  I have no problem compiling it in VC.

Comment: Ah, you just can't help but smile at those g++ outputs. So full of love, they are.

Comment: I did some research thinking it was just going to be like std::toupper and ::toupper are different in some suttle way which transform doesn't handle but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Comeau Online compiles the code as well and so does Intel C++

Comment: @Santiago Lezica: Not that hard to read (Add a bit of formatting).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't work because there are overloads of `std::toupper`. You can fix it by casting to your desired function overload:

```
std::transform(s.begin(),s.end(), std::back_inserter(S),
                (int(&)(int))std::toupper);
```

Comment: This is a better answer. Found a little similar discussion at [usenet](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.g++.help/browse_thread/thread/f90fd07a42ae9462/) too.

Comment: Well there is an argument for introducing a new version of all the cctype function for C++ (that take and return char) if ever I saw one. These function accept and return int so that they can deal with EOF character.

Comment: Also shows I should learn to read the error message. It explains the exact problem.

Comment: @GMan: I think the question is not what should be done to make it work; after all `::toupper` already works. So the question is, why does `std::toupper` not work? Should it not work as we clearly mentioned the namespace `std`?

Comment: @Nawaz: Like I said, because `std::toupper` has overloads.

Comment: @GMan: Within `std` namespace?

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, from importing `::toupper` and from `<locale>`: `template <typename C> C toupper(C c, const locale& l);`. Just specifying `std::toupper` isn't valid for an argument, because it could be either. By casting, it eliminates one overload.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing that C++ *also* adds new `toupper` functions in `<locale>` which is probably included implicitly by one of your other headers. Thus in the `std::` namespace there are multiple overloads while in the global namespace there is only the old C version of the function.

That said it does still seem like g++ should be able to deduce the correct overload.

Answer (score 2):

Like others said the problem is that std::toupper and friends are overloaded.
One way to fix this is to use a lambda.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string s{ "This is a test" };
   std::string S{};
   std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(S), [] (char ch){ return std::toupper(ch); });
   std::cout << S;
   return 0;
}
```

I realize this is an old post but as many, including myself, still encounter this issue, I hope my post will be helpful.

Comment: Nice. This would also resolve the issue.